# Placing tikzpikture

Tags: floats, wrap

I want to put tikzpicture at the right of the text

```
\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}


 \item Схема, изображённая на рис. 9.2, состоит из четырёх резисторов, идеального амперметра и ключа К. Сопротивления всех резисторов указаны на рисунке. Если ключ замкнут, амперметр показывает значение $I_{1}=0,5 A$. Какое значение силы тока $I_{2}$ будет показывать амперметр, если ключ разомкнуть? Напряжение в цепи в обоих случаях одинаковое.

\begin{tikzpicture}


\raggedright
\draw (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (0.9,3);
\draw (2.1,3) -- (3,3)-- (3.9,3);
\draw (0.9,2.8) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,3.2);
\draw (3.9,2.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (5.1,3.2);
\draw (3,3) -- (3,1.9);
\draw (3,1.1) -- (3,0);
\draw (3,1.5)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

\draw (0.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,0.2);
\draw (3.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (5.1,0.2);

\draw (2.1,0) -- (3,0)-- (3.2,0) -- node[above] {\large K} (3.6,0.2);
\draw (3.7,0) -- (3.9,0);
\draw (5.1,3) -- (6,3) -- (6,0) -- (5.1,0);

\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1)-- (2.7,-1);
\draw (6,0) -- (6,-1)-- (3.3,-1);
\draw (2.75,-1)circle(0.05cm) ;
\draw (3.25,-1)circle(0.05cm);


\end{tikzpicture}



\item 


\end{enumerate}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

i want get result 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. TikZ image is not related to your desired output. The same is with any kind of image or table. See, if `wrapfig` package (http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zarko said in the comment, this is more of a float placement problem than a TikZ problem. The desired output can be achieved using the `wrapfig` package. However, you may not use `wrapfig` within list environments such as `enumerate`, as you did in your example.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (0.9,3);
  \draw (2.1,3) -- (3,3)-- (3.9,3);
  \draw (0.9,2.8) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,3.2);
  \draw (3.9,2.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (5.1,3.2);
  \draw (3,3) -- (3,1.9);
  \draw (3,1.1) -- (3,0);
  \draw (3,1.5)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

  \draw (0.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,0.2);
  \draw (3.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (5.1,0.2);

  \draw (2.1,0) -- (3,0)-- (3.2,0) -- node[above] {\large K} (3.6,0.2);
  \draw (3.7,0) -- (3.9,0);
  \draw (5.1,3) -- (6,3) -- (6,0) -- (5.1,0);

  \draw (0,0) -- (0,-1)-- (2.7,-1);
  \draw (6,0) -- (6,-1)-- (3.3,-1);
  \draw (2.75,-1)circle(0.05cm) ;
  \draw (3.25,-1)circle(0.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]